# How do I increase Search API quota on App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

I keep receiving errors in my app like

> OverQuotaError: The API call search.DeleteDocument() required more quota than is available.

I can't find anywhere in my dashboard to adjust these quotas - only see what they are.  How can this be done?

Comment: normally you would enable billing - have you?

Comment: Yes, billing is enabled and I'm using a F4_1G instance.

Comment: it's not one of the "per second safety limits" is it? How often do you call that?

Comment: It is possible that it is - but I don't know how to see that, all my quotas claim they are "Okay."  It gets called not too often, probably less than once an hour on average.